# Android, Make an image at a URL equal to ImageView's image

Tags: android

I'm wondering how would I make an image that is located at a specific URL equal to an ImageView's image?

Comment: Do you mean load an ImageView with an Image from a URL? Or upload an Image from an ImageView to a specific URL.

Answer (score 148, accepted):

To download an image and set it as content for an imageview

```
try {
  ImageView i = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.image);
  Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream((InputStream)new URL(imageUrl).getContent());
  i.setImageBitmap(bitmap); 
} catch (MalformedURLException e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: really nice code buddy , i searched a lot but didn't found this kind of simple example

Comment: Edit : Removed redundant comment! :)

Comment: and what about caching for your solution? Where does loaded image stay? Is it cached or not?

Comment: Works like Gem!

Answer (score 7):

```
  // Url = "url of image"
  Drawable drawable = LoadImageFromWebOperations(Url);
  mImageofTheMonth.setImageDrawable(drawable);

private Drawable LoadImageFromWebOperations(String url) {

    try {
        InputStream is = (InputStream) new URL(url).getContent();
        Drawable d = Drawable.createFromStream(is, "src name");
        return d;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Exc=" + e);
        return null;
    }

}
```

Comment: Do you think it is better to store the image locally on the device or just store the url to the image online instead? (assuming the image will always be there)

Answer (score 5):

Since i don't have enough points to add a comment, I will make a post...

Remember to put @primpap's answer in **AsyncTask doInBackground** to prevent UI thread to freeze.

Answer (score 3):

```
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        ArrayList<ItemDetails> image_details = GetSearchResults();

        final ListView lv1 = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listV_main);
        lv1.setAdapter(new ItemListBaseAdapter(this, image_details));

        lv1.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> a, View v, int position, long id) { 

                // Launching new Activity on selecting single List Item
                Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ItemDetails.class);

                Object o = lv1.getItemAtPosition(position);
                ItemDetails obj_itemDetails = (ItemDetails)o;

                // sending data to new activity
                i.putExtra("name", obj_itemDetails.getName());
                i.putExtra("description", obj_itemDetails.getItemDescription());
                i.putExtra("imagenumber", obj_itemDetails.getImageNumber());

                **ItemDetails.IMAGE_NUMBER = obj_itemDetails.getImageNumber();**
                startActivity(i);
            }   
        });
    }
```

Use Static Variable to get the Image ID and then Load it Dynamically. Check the IMAGE_Number.