# Load image from url

Tags: android

I have an image URL. I want to display an image from this URL in an ImageView but I am unable to do that.

How can this be achieved?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to load an ImageView by URL in Android?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2471935/how-to-load-an-imageview-by-url-in-android)

Comment: look these questions and focus at the first answers, here you can find two simple and complete ways to do this: [first method (more complete)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2471935/how-to-load-an-imageview-by-url-in-android) or [second method (more simply)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3118691/android-make-an-image-at-a-url-equal-to-imageviews-image)

Comment: you can use Picasso and Glide image loader and displayed to imageview

Answer (score 269, accepted):

```
URL url = new URL("http://image10.bizrate-images.com/resize?sq=60&uid=2216744464");
Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(url.openConnection().getInputStream());
imageView.setImageBitmap(bmp);
```

Comment: You really ought to not to use that, as it blocks the UI thread.

This library will handle threading and downloading for you:

https://github.com/koush/UrlImageViewHelper

Comment: Not if u run that block on a seperate thread minus the setImageBitmap

Comment: its working i displaying in thumbnails and onclick imageview i used dsplaying dailog but it opens after 10secs

Comment: @koush - This code would be fine if wrapped in an `AsyncTask`.

Comment: You should make any networl operations in a separate thread, When bitmap has been loaded, you could use ImageView.post() or Handler.post()

Comment: Just a note that method call BitmapFactory.decodeStream(url.openConnection().getInputStream()) on main thread or inside runOnUIThread() will cause android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException. I've used same code, but I've created new thread and run it inside them and it's working fine. Setting bitmap image on image view needs to be implemented inside runOnUIThread()

Answer (score 331):

The accepted answer above is great if you are loading the image based on a button click, however if you are doing it in a new activity it freezes up the UI for a second or two. Looking around I found that a simple asynctask eliminated this problem.

To use an asynctask to add this class at the end of your activity:

```
private class DownloadImageTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap> {
  ImageView bmImage;

  public DownloadImageTask(ImageView bmImage) {
      this.bmImage = bmImage;
  }

  protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... urls) {
      String urldisplay = urls[0];
      Bitmap mIcon11 = null;
      try {
        InputStream in = new java.net.URL(urldisplay).openStream();
        mIcon11 = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in);
      } catch (Exception e) {
          Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());
          e.printStackTrace();
      }
      return mIcon11;
  }

  protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result) {
      bmImage.setImageBitmap(result);
  }
}
```

And call from your onCreate() method using:

```
new DownloadImageTask((ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1))
        .execute(MY_URL_STRING);
```

Dont forget to add below permission in your manifest file

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```

Works great for me.  :)

Comment: this is great. @Sofija what did you mean with cleanup? what if you have unknown number of pictures?

Comment: @5er I had some of the brackets out of place in the original answer. I've since cleaned it up so you should be able to use it as is.

Comment: Not to forget that we need to also add permission in manifest: <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>

Comment: This is awesome for learning/hacking (upvoted) but for anything production you should use a Imageloader library, theres so many out there. My favorite one is Universal Image loader, Picasso etc.

Comment: You should use Glide or Picasso

Comment: How to add centerCrop?

Comment: How to put it into HashMap: map.put("img",) new DownloadImageTask((?.execute(surl));

Answer (score 47):

try `picasso` nice and finishes in one statement

```
Picasso.with(context)
                .load(ImageURL)
                .resize(width,height).into(imageView);
```

tutorial:
https://youtu.be/DxRqxsEPc2s

(**note:** [`Picasso.with()` has been renamed to `Picasso.get()`](https://github.com/twitter-archive/twitter-kit-android/issues/143) in the latest release)

Comment: Picasso, Glide are my favorites, also. The statement of Glide is quite similar to Picasso, with much improvement in cache size.

Comment: This should be the new answer,  although its always nice to know how to do it on your own.  Great article explaining both ways:  https://medium.com/@crossphd/android-image-loading-from-a-string-url-6c8290b82c5e

Comment: for loading url which is better Picasso or Glide in terms of performance?

Answer (score 12):

**There are two ways:**

**1) Using Glide library** This is the best way to load an image from a URL because when you try to display the same URL the second time it will display from the cache so improving app performance

```
Glide.with(context).load("YourUrl").into(imageView);
```

dependency :  `implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.10.0'`

**2) Using Stream** Here you want to create a bitmap from a URL image

```
URL url = new URL("YourUrl");
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(url.openConnection().getInputStream());
imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
```

Comment: To use Glide, you need to also add this line to the Manifest.xml:
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
Sorry for the necro-post. I've upvoted your answer as Glide worked for me.

Comment: Your "catch" should be spelled as "cache".

Answer (score 9):

Try this
add picasso lib jar file

```
Picasso.with(context)
                .load(ImageURL)
                .resize(width,height).noFade().into(imageView);
```

Answer (score 7):

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;

import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class imageDownload {

    Bitmap bmImg;
    void downloadfile(String fileurl,ImageView img)
    {
        URL myfileurl =null;
        try
        {
            myfileurl= new URL(fileurl);

        }
        catch (MalformedURLException e)
        {

            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        try
        {
            HttpURLConnection conn= (HttpURLConnection)myfileurl.openConnection();
            conn.setDoInput(true);
            conn.connect();
            int length = conn.getContentLength();
            int[] bitmapData =new int[length];
            byte[] bitmapData2 =new byte[length];
            InputStream is = conn.getInputStream();
            BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();

            bmImg = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is,null,options);

            img.setImageBitmap(bmImg);

            //dialog.dismiss();
            } 
        catch(IOException e)
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
//          Toast.makeText(PhotoRating.this, "Connection Problem. Try Again.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }


    }


}
```

in your activity
take imageview & set resource
imageDownload(url,yourImageview);

Answer (score 6):

Based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10868126/2956344) i write my own loader.

With Loading effect and Appear effect :

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.util.DisplayMetrics;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.view.animation.AlphaAnimation;
import android.view.animation.Animation;
import android.widget.FrameLayout;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;

import java.io.InputStream;

/**
 * Created by Sergey Shustikov (pandarium.shustikov@gmail.com) at 2015.
 */
public class DownloadImageTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap>
{
    public static final int ANIMATION_DURATION = 250;
    private final ImageView mDestination, mFakeForError;
    private final String mUrl;
    private final ProgressBar mProgressBar;
    private Animation.AnimationListener mOutAnimationListener = new Animation.AnimationListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation)
        {

        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation)
        {
            mProgressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation)
        {

        }
    };
    private Animation.AnimationListener mInAnimationListener = new Animation.AnimationListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation)
        {
            if (isBitmapSet)
                mDestination.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            else
                mFakeForError.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation)
        {

        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation)
        {

        }
    };
    private boolean isBitmapSet;

    public DownloadImageTask(Context context, ImageView destination, String url)
    {
        mDestination = destination;
        mUrl = url;
        ViewGroup parent = (ViewGroup) destination.getParent();
        mFakeForError = new ImageView(context);
        destination.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        FrameLayout layout = new FrameLayout(context);
        mProgressBar = new ProgressBar(context);
        FrameLayout.LayoutParams params = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        params.gravity = Gravity.CENTER;
        mProgressBar.setLayoutParams(params);
        FrameLayout.LayoutParams copy = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        copy.gravity = Gravity.CENTER;
        copy.width = dpToPx(48);
        copy.height = dpToPx(48);
        mFakeForError.setLayoutParams(copy);
        mFakeForError.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        mFakeForError.setImageResource(android.R.drawable.ic_menu_close_clear_cancel);
        layout.addView(mProgressBar);
        layout.addView(mFakeForError);
        mProgressBar.setIndeterminate(true);
        parent.addView(layout, new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
    }

    protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... urls)
    {
        String urlDisplay = mUrl;
        Bitmap bitmap = null;
        try {
            InputStream in = new java.net.URL(urlDisplay).openStream();
            bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return bitmap;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result)
    {
        AlphaAnimation in = new AlphaAnimation(0f, 1f);
        AlphaAnimation out = new AlphaAnimation(1f, 0f);
        in.setDuration(ANIMATION_DURATION * 2);
        out.setDuration(ANIMATION_DURATION);
        out.setAnimationListener(mOutAnimationListener);
        in.setAnimationListener(mInAnimationListener);
        in.setStartOffset(ANIMATION_DURATION);
        if (result != null) {
            mDestination.setImageBitmap(result);
            isBitmapSet = true;
            mDestination.startAnimation(in);
        } else {
            mFakeForError.startAnimation(in);
        }
        mProgressBar.startAnimation(out);
    }
    public int dpToPx(int dp) {
        DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = mDestination.getContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
        int px = Math.round(dp * (displayMetrics.xdpi / DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_DEFAULT));
        return px;
    }
}
```

Add permission

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```

And execute :

```
 new DownloadImageTask(context, imageViewToLoad, urlToImage).execute();
```

Comment: goodjob sergey.

Answer (score 5):

UrlImageViewHelper will fill an ImageView with an image that is found at a URL. UrlImageViewHelper will automatically download, save, and cache all the image urls the BitmapDrawables. Duplicate urls will not be loaded into memory twice. Bitmap memory is managed by using a weak reference hash table, so as soon as the image is no longer used by you, it will be garbage collected automatically.

UrlImageViewHelper.setUrlDrawable(imageView, "http://example.com/image.png");

https://github.com/koush/UrlImageViewHelper

Answer (score 5):

add Internet permission in manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

than create methode as below,

```
 public static Bitmap getBitmapFromURL(String src) {
    try {
        Log.e("src", src);
        URL url = new URL(src);
        HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        connection.setDoInput(true);
        connection.connect();
        InputStream input = connection.getInputStream();
        Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input);
        Log.e("Bitmap", "returned");
        return myBitmap;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Log.e("Exception", e.getMessage());
        return null;
    }
}
```

now add this in your onCreate method,

```
 ImageView img_add = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.img_add);


img_add.setImageBitmap(getBitmapFromURL("http://www.deepanelango.me/wpcontent/uploads/2017/06/noyyal1.jpg"));
```

this is works for me.

Answer (score 4):

Here is sample code for display Image from URL.

```
public static Void downloadfile(String fileurl, ImageView img) {
        Bitmap bmImg = null;
        URL myfileurl = null;
        try {
            myfileurl = new URL(fileurl);
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {
            HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) myfileurl.openConnection();
            conn.setDoInput(true);
            conn.connect();
            int length = conn.getContentLength();
            if (length > 0) {
                int[] bitmapData = new int[length];
                byte[] bitmapData2 = new byte[length];
                InputStream is = conn.getInputStream();
                bmImg = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is);
                img.setImageBitmap(bmImg);
            }

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

Best Method I have tried instead of using any libraries

```
public Bitmap getbmpfromURL(String surl){
    try {
        URL url = new URL(surl);
        HttpURLConnection urlcon = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        urlcon.setDoInput(true);
        urlcon.connect();
        InputStream in = urlcon.getInputStream();
        Bitmap mIcon = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in);
        return  mIcon;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    Bitmap b;
    ImageView img;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        img = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
        information info = new information();
        info.execute("");
    }

    public class information extends AsyncTask<String, String, String>
    {
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... arg0) {

            try
            {
                URL url = new URL("http://10.119.120.10:80/img.jpg");
                InputStream is = new BufferedInputStream(url.openStream());
                b = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is);

            } catch(Exception e){}
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            img.setImageBitmap(b);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: AsyncTask is deprecated.

Comment: @BokiliProduction this code was posted in year 2015 as a recommended practice. Now the API is ofcourse depricated.

Comment: OK, I was just commenting that some people would not go deeper into unnecessary waste of time. There are much simpler and faster solutions than AsyncTask. I salute you my friend.

Answer (score 2):

The code below show you how to set ImageView from a url string, using RxAndroid.
First, add RxAndroid library 2.0

```
dependencies {
    // RxAndroid
    compile 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxandroid:2.0.0'
    compile 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxjava:2.0.0'

    // Utilities
    compile 'org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.5'

}
```

now use setImageFromUrl to set image.

```
public void setImageFromUrl(final ImageView imageView, final String urlString) {

    Observable.just(urlString)
        .filter(new Predicate<String>() {
            @Override public boolean test(String url) throws Exception {
                return StringUtils.isNotBlank(url);
            }
        })
        .map(new Function<String, Drawable>() {
            @Override public Drawable apply(String s) throws Exception {
                URL url = null;
                try {
                    url = new URL(s);
                    return Drawable.createFromStream((InputStream) url.getContent(), "profile");
                } catch (final IOException ex) {
                    return null;
                }
            }
        })
        .filter(new Predicate<Drawable>() {
            @Override public boolean test(Drawable drawable) throws Exception {
                return drawable != null;
            }
        })
        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
        .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
        .subscribe(new Consumer<Drawable>() {
            @Override public void accept(Drawable drawable) throws Exception {
                imageView.setImageDrawable(drawable);
            }
        });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
loadImage("http://relinjose.com/directory/filename.png");
```

Here you go

```
void loadImage(String image_location) {
    URL imageURL = null;
    if (image_location != null) {
        try {
            imageURL = new URL(image_location);         
            HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) imageURL
                    .openConnection();
            connection.setDoInput(true);
            connection.connect();
            InputStream inputStream = connection.getInputStream();
            bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream);// Convert to bitmap
            ivdpfirst.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    } else {
        //set any default
    }
}
```

Comment: What's `ivdpfirst`?

Comment: Id of ImageView used in the xml design.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
InputStream input = contentResolver.openInputStream(httpuri);
Bitmap b = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input, null, options);
```

Answer (score 1):

To me, [Fresco](https://frescolib.org/) is the best among the other Libraries.

Just [setup](http://frescolib.org/docs/getting-started.html) Fresco and then simply set the ImageURI like this:

```
draweeView.setImageURI(uri);
```

Check out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29567946/4872155) answer explaining some of Fresco Benefits.

Answer (score 0):

This is my working solution using Adrian's code example:

```
private void loadImage(String pUrl) {
    Thread imageDataThread = new Thread(() -> {
        try {
            URL tUrl = new URL(pUrl);
            Bitmap imageBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(tUrl.openConnection().getInputStream());
            runOnUiThread(() -> image_preview.setImageBitmap(imageBitmap));
        } catch(IOException pExc) {
            showToast("Error loading image for this question!");
            pExc.printStackTrace();
        }
    });
    imageDataThread.start();
}
```

Note: You can use this pre-defined method to load image bitmap or you can use yours in case you need to resize image or some similar operation over image.

Comment: What is image_preview?

Comment: It's a ImageView