# Load an image from url on button click

Tags: android

How to load an image from url on a button click and that image will be showed on activity itself?

I try the following code but it shows the system error like java.net.UnknownHostException Host is on resolved.

```
package com.v3.thread.fetchImage;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;

import org.apache.http.HttpException;
import org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class MainThreadActivity extends Activity {
    ImageView img_downloaded;
    Button btn_download;
    String fileurl = "http://variable3.com/files/images/email-sig.jpg";

Bitmap bmImg;
private ProgressDialog dialog;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    //new MainThreadActivity().onPreExecute();

    img_downloaded = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
    btn_download = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnLoad);

    btn_download.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            try {
                downloadfile(fileurl);
            } catch (HttpHostConnectException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (HttpException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
}


public void AbstractProgressTask() {
    dialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
}

protected void onPreExecute() {new MainThreadActivity().onPreExecute();
    this.dialog.setMessage("Loading. Please wait...");
    this.dialog.show();
}

 /**
 * method is called after the work is done.
 *
 * @param success result of #doInBackground method.
 */

protected void onPostExecute(final Boolean success) {
    if (dialog.isShowing()) {
        dialog.dismiss();
    }
}
// automatically done on worker thread (separate from UI thread)
protected Boolean doInBackground(final String... args) {

  // here is your code
  return true;
}

void downloadfile(String fileurl) throws HttpException,HttpHostConnectException {
    URL myFileUrl = null;
    try {
        myFileUrl = new URL(fileurl);
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    try {
        HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) myFileUrl.openConnection();
        conn.setDoInput(true);
        conn.connect();
        int length = conn.getContentLength();
        if(length>0)
        {
            InputStream is = conn.getInputStream();
            bmImg = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is);
            img_download.setImageBitmap(bmImg);
        }
        else
        {
            InputStream is = conn.getInputStream();
            bmImg = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is);
        }

    } 
    catch(IOException e)
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
}

        {
            int[] bitmapData =new int[length];
            byte[] bitmapData2 =new byte[length];
            InputStream is = conn.getInputStream();
            bmImg = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is);
        }

    } 
    catch(IOException e)
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
}

}
```

Comment: Man, googling is so hard. Did you even try the highest related question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5776851/load-image-from-url Now you just have to find out how you add a listener to a button! I wonder if Google will tell you how to do that.

Comment: UnknownHostException is raised if a) there is no internet connection b) host name is wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.x);

    Button butt = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.Button01);
    imageView =(ImageView) findViewById(R.id.ImageView01);
    Bitmap image;

    butt.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
        public void onClick(View v)  {
            URL url = null;
            try {
                url = new URL("http://lh5.ggpht.com/_hepKlJWopDg/TB-_WXikaYI/AAAAAAAAElI/715k4NvBM4w/s144-c/IMG_0075.JPG");
            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            try {
                image = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(url.openStream());
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            imageView.setImageBitmap(image);
        }
        });
}
```

Dont forget to include the following permission if you download image from net.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>
```

Answer (score 2):

You should launch `AsyncTask` with `ProgressDialog` bounded(see an [example](http://it-projects.spb.ru/?p=150&lang=en)) on button click. This is made by setting onClickListener on the button. In that AsyncTask you should download an image(see [here](http://www.helloandroid.com/tutorials/how-download-fileimage-url-your-device)). After you have dowloaded this, just call a method on your activity from `onPostExecute()` to show the image.