# Set button background image from url

Tags: android, eclipse, button, background-image

I was wondering how i set a buttons background image from a URL on android. 
The buttons id is blue if you need to know that.

I tried this but it didn't work.

```
    public static Bitmap loadBitmap(String url) {
    Bitmap bitmap = null;
    InputStream in = null;
    BufferedOutputStream out = null;

    try {
    in = new BufferedInputStream(new URL(url).openStream(), IO_BUFFER_SIZE);

    final ByteArrayOutputStream dataStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    out = new BufferedOutputStream(dataStream, IO_BUFFER_SIZE);
    copy(in, out);
    out.flush();

    final byte[] data = dataStream.toByteArray();
    BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    //options.inSampleSize = 1;

    bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(data, 0, data.length,options);
    } catch (IOException e) {
    Log.e(TAG, "Could not load Bitmap from: " + url);
    } finally {
    closeStream(in);
    closeStream(out);
    }

    return bitmap;
    }
```

Comment: If you want to do it effeciently, take a look into this http://goo.gl/i15Yn

Answer (score 1):

I used the next code for obtain the bitmap, one important thing is sometimes you can't obtain the InputStream, and that is null, I make 3 attemps if that happens.

```
public Bitmap generateBitmap(String url){
    bitmap_picture = null;

    int intentos = 0;
    boolean exception = true;
    while((exception) && (intentos < 3)){
        try {
            URL imageURL = new URL(url);
            HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) imageURL.openConnection();
            conn.connect();
            InputStream bitIs = conn.getInputStream();
            if(bitIs != null){
                bitmap_picture = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(bitIs);
                exception = false;
            }else{
                Log.e("InputStream", "Viene null");
            }
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            exception = true;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            exception = true;
        }
        intentos++;
    }

    return bitmap_picture;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't load the image directly in the UI (main) thread, for it will make the UI freeze while the image is being loaded. Do it in a separate thread instead, for example using an `AsyncTask`. The AsyncTask will let the image load in its `doInBackground()` method and then it can be set as the button background image in the `onPostExecute()` method.  See this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10868126/2241463

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
Bitmap bmpbtn = loadBitmap(yoururl);

button1.setImageBitmap(bmpbtn);
```