# Set the background of a View from a string URL

Tags: android, imageview

I want to set the background of a view from a string URL. I used this code to set an image from drawable:

[The sample URL](http://www.image.com/image.png)

```
View rightv = row.findViewById(R.id.four);
rightv.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.demoimage);
rightv.setTag(position);
rightv.setOnClickListener(MembersDealActivity_a.this);
```

But when I tried to do the same from the URL, it did not work. I tried this sort of code too, but it did not work either:

```
Drawable res = getResources().getDrawable(imageResource);
right.setBackgroundDrawable(res);
right.setTag(position);
right.setOnClickListener(MembersDealActivity_a.this);
```

I also have tried to use the Picasso library, but when it request to set a value into parameter view it can't be cast there.

```
Picasso.with(this)
    .load(imag_link).resize(600, 350)
    .into(imv);
```

The full code:

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity implements
        AdapterView.OnItemClickListener, View.OnClickListener {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        ListView list = new ListView(this);
        setContentView(list);

        String[] items = { "Tom", "Sally", "Bill", "John", "Santiago",
                "Isabella" };

        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                R.layout.review, R.id.textView1, items) {
            @Override
            public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
                View row = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);


                View text = row.findViewById(R.id.seemore);
                text.setTag(position);
                text.setOnClickListener(MyActivity.this);



                View left = row.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
                left.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.newapture);
                left.setTag(position);
                left.setOnClickListener(MyActivity.this);


                return row;
            }
        };
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5776851/load-image-from-url

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use This code may this help you...

`URL url = new URL(Your URL);

Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(url.openConnection().getInputStream());
imageView.setImageBitmap(bmp);`

Or refer these link [Click Here](https://github.com/koush/UrlImageViewHelper)

Comment: URL url = new URL(imagename); 
        Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(url.openConnection().getInputStream()); 
        right.setImageBitmap(bmp);     ..... i tried to do this and saying me to add cast to my imageview and when i did so nothing happesn

Comment: what is (right) in your code... means of which class object it is??

Comment: like,    imageview.setImageURI(Uri.parse("Your string"));

Answer (score 2):

Set the background of a view inside Async task because you are getting image from url.
Try it I hope it will help you.

Answer (score 1):

try this..`URL url = new URL(Your Url);
Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(url.openConnection().getInputStream());
imageView.setImageBitmap(bmp);`

Answer (score 1):

you can try this one

```
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(imageUrl.openConnection().getInputStream());
BitmapDrawable background = new BitmapDrawable(getResources(), bitmap);
rightv.setBackgroundDrawable(background);
```

Answer (score 0):

i`m using a class for load Image into ImageView from URL:

Here: 
1. create a class ImageFromUrlUtil.java

```
package com.ntjp.halalnavi.guide.util;

import android.graphics.Bitmap.Config;
import android.widget.ImageView;

import com.ntjp.halalnavi.guide.R;
import com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.DisplayImageOptions;
import com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.ImageLoader;
import com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.assist.ImageScaleType;
import com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.display.FadeInBitmapDisplayer;
import com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.display.RoundedBitmapDisplayer;
import com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.listener.ImageLoadingListener;

public class ImageFromUrlUtil {

    public static void displayImage(ImageView view, String path, ImageLoadingListener listener) {
        ImageLoader loader = ImageLoader.getInstance();
        try {
            loader.displayImage(path, view, DEFAULT_DISPLAY_IMAGE_OPTIONS, listener);
        } catch (OutOfMemoryError e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            loader.clearMemoryCache();
        }
    }

    public static void displayRoundImage(ImageView view, String path, ImageLoadingListener listener) {
        ImageLoader loader = ImageLoader.getInstance();
        try {
            loader.displayImage(path, view, ROUND_DISPLAY_IMAGE_OPTIONS, listener);
        } catch (OutOfMemoryError e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            loader.clearMemoryCache();
        }
    }

    public static void loadImage(String path, ImageLoadingListener listener) {
        ImageLoader loader = ImageLoader.getInstance();
        try {
            loader.loadImage(path, DEFAULT_DISPLAY_IMAGE_OPTIONS, listener);
        } catch (OutOfMemoryError e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    //TODO Change default image
    private static final DisplayImageOptions.Builder DEFAULT_DISPLAY_IMAGE_OPTIONS_BUIDLER = new DisplayImageOptions.Builder()
            .imageScaleType(ImageScaleType.IN_SAMPLE_POWER_OF_2)
            .displayer(new FadeInBitmapDisplayer(300, true, false, false))
            .showImageForEmptyUri(R.drawable.default_image)
            .showImageOnLoading(R.drawable.default_image)
            .showImageOnFail(R.drawable.default_image).cacheOnDisk(true)
            .cacheInMemory(true).bitmapConfig(Config.ARGB_8888);

    private static final DisplayImageOptions DEFAULT_DISPLAY_IMAGE_OPTIONS = DEFAULT_DISPLAY_IMAGE_OPTIONS_BUIDLER
            .build();
    private static final DisplayImageOptions ROUND_DISPLAY_IMAGE_OPTIONS = DEFAULT_DISPLAY_IMAGE_OPTIONS_BUIDLER
            .displayer(new RoundedBitmapDisplayer(500)).build();
}
```

then call this method from anywhere you want:

for a rounded Image us:

```
ImageUtil.displayRoundImage(avt, avtUrl, null);
```

for a normal Image us:

```
ImageUtil.displayImage(thumb, avtUrl, null);
```

Finaly add this Library to your project: [Link](https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader/tree/master/library)

Answer (score 0):

For set image as wallpaper you can use this..

```
wallpaperManager=WallpaperManager.getInstance(getApplicationContext());
StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder()
            .permitAll().build();
StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);

// Button Onclick

 setWallpaper.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
      @Override
      public void onClick(View v) {
            InputStream ins = null;
            try {
                  ins = new URL(url).openStream();
                  wallpaperManager.setStream(ins);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                  e.printStackTrace();
            }
            FancyToast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Set Successfully", 
            FancyToast.LENGTH_SHORT, FancyToast.SUCCESS, false).show();
        }
     });
```

Please add the permissions in AndroidManifest.xml of Set_Wallpaper and Internet.