# get the URI of an image at runtime

Tags: android, runtime, uri

How to get the URI of an image at runtime.
I am trying to load an image using URI after the app is installed on the device. But everytime it shows the problem "Unable to load".
I'm using every syntax to load the URI from drawable and assets, but nothing works. I guess after installation of the app, it can't get the drawable folder.
Can anyone help me how to fetch the image URI after the app is installed on the device.

Comment: I have to crop the image using the default gallery crop feature. For that I need the URI of the image. So i can't use the WebView. Any help..

Comment: Why do you want to crop it? Just place it in the `ImageView` of size whatever you want to crop into.

Comment: I have to provide a crop feature in my app, where user can crop the image himself.

Comment: [This](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/07/android-loading-image-from-url-http/) link might help you.

Comment: and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5776851/load-image-from-url) too.