# Lazy loading image like tumblr on Android

Tags: android, webview, tumblr

On Tumblr, with the post have many images. They will be previewed by a local image. And then, when user click to, they will be replaced by real image.
I want to do like that.
I have a listview, each item as a post having a webview. I got html string, I replace src of img tag by local image. But I couldn't catch touching event on webview ( webview in listview)

```
            holder.webView.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View web, MotionEvent event) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                WebView.HitTestResult result = ((WebView)holder.webView).getHitTestResult();
                if (result == null) {
                    return false;
                }
                int type = result.getType();
                String extra = result.getExtra();


                return false;
            }
        });
```

result  variable is always null ??? So the first question: how can I catch the event (touching in img in webview) ?

And then, the second question: How can I replace the touched img (local img)  in webview by a real img ( I have the img url) ?
Thank in advanced!

Comment: r u trying to set the touch event in adapter

Comment: yes :) what wrong ? Let me know the better way, plz ?

Comment: have u tried listitemclick in ur activity

Comment: I haven't setted listener for whole item.
Each item has some controls.

Comment: not sure why you want the onTouchLisetener why not setOnClickListener(View.OnClickListener l)?

Answer (score 2):

Can you try

```
WebView.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() 
{
   public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
   }
});
```

and for loading image from URL [Load image from url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5776851/load-image-from-url)
please follow the above link.

Comment: 1st question: I have already tried it, but it didn't work.
2nd question: thank you, but in my case, I want to load image from URL to webview, replace local image ( preview image)