# Show image from server URL in ImageView

Tags: android

I need to show the image from url but my code does not work
I try this:

```
File file = new File(imagePathFromServer);
Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(file);
((ImageView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.image)).setImageURI(uri);
```

How to show it? The `imagePathFromServer` is correct (I can open it in browser)

Comment: Hope you have tried to Google it. If not then do it and also search existing threads on Stackoverflow. You will find plenty of examples.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Load image from url](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5776851/load-image-from-url)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try below code:-

```
    ImageLoaderConfiguration config = new ImageLoaderConfiguration.Builder(getApplicationContext()).defaultDisplayImageOptions(options)
            .build();
    ImageLoader.getInstance().init(config);

ImageLoader.getInstance().displayImage(Uri.parse(imgURL).toString(), imgPost);
```

**lib**

https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader

Answer (score 1):

Download the [picasso library](http://square.github.io/picasso/) and add to your project vía jar, maven or gradle. Then,

Example  in one line of code:

```
 Picasso.with(context).load("http://example.com/logo.png").into(imageView);
```

Comment: Keep in mind that Picasso take care of your caching properties and such.

Comment: after trying it throws an exception java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.squareup.picasso.Picasso

Comment: You probably missing a linker or something since you are getting NoClassDefFoundError exception. Check your build options to see if you added the library properly.