# Retrieving images using json in android

Tags: android, json

I am trying to build an android application. I want to retrieve data from a website (.php) using JSON. So far I am able to get the recent post's title, URL and the the respective content but how can I retrieve image of that particular post? Thank you.

this is a piece of the code:

```
private TextView techPostCount, techPostTitle, techPostUrl, techPostContent, techPostAuthor 

private ImageView techImages;

.
.
.

int jsonArrLength = jsonMainNode.length();

            for(int i=0; i < jsonArrLength; i++) {

                JSONObject jsonChildNode = jsonMainNode.getJSONObject(i);
                String postTitle = jsonChildNode.getString("slug");
                String postUrl = jsonChildNode.getString("url");
                String postContent=jsonChildNode.getString("content");
                String postImage=jsonChildNode.getString("author");

                techcPostCount.setText("Number of posts:" +postCount);
                techPostTitle.setText("Page :" +postTitle);
                techPostUrl.setText("Page URL:" +postUrl);
                techPostContent.setText("Article:"+ postContent);

                techclinchPostImage?????("Picture:"+ ????);
```

Comment: where is this image located? is the location of the image passed to you in the JSON reply ?

Comment: It's quite common Json contains only a link to images, not the image data. Isn't this the case for you?

Comment: Do you have the image URL?

Comment: Please post an example of the json object you receive. What kind of site are you getting this json object from, is it yours or is it third-party?

Comment: yes, there is a link to the image..but how to get the whole image? any suggestions?

Comment: @SachinSharma See the answer on using `Picasso`

Comment: possible duplicate of [Load image from url](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5776851/load-image-from-url)

Comment: "thumbnail" : "http://www.techclinch.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/Nanyang-Technology-University.jpg",
        "thumbnail_images" : { "full" : { "height" : 370,
                "url" : "http://www.techclinch.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/Nanyang-Technology-University.jpg",
                "width" : 620
              },

Comment: Thanks CurlyCorvous, Little Child, Muthu, harism,

Comment: Is the looping ok? because i am getting only the recent post..just one. how to retrieve all the posts?

Answer (score 2):

To display an image in an `ImageView` from a URI, you have to download the image first then put the downloaded image in the `ImageView`.

Or you can consider using [Picasso](http://square.github.io/picasso/) to just let it do all this work for you

```
// context here can be the Activity or its application context
Picasso.with(context)
    .load(postImage)
    .into(techclinchPostImage);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can download Images in a separate Thread like this

```
 private class LoadImage extends AsyncTask<String, String, Bitmap> {
            ImageView img=null;
            public LoadImage(ImageView img){
                this.img=img;
            }
            @Override
            protected void onPreExecute() {
                super.onPreExecute();

            }
            protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... args) {
                Bitmap bitmap=null;
                try {
                    bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream((InputStream)new URL(args[0]).getContent());
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                return bitmap;
            }
            protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap image) {
                if(img != null && image != null){
                    img.setImageBitmap(image);
                }
            }
        }`
```

add the above code to your project. and you call it like this

```
 ImageView techclinchPostImage =findViewbyId....
 new LoadImage(techclinchPostImage).execute("Your URL");
```