# View Flipper : how to use large number of images?

Tags: android, out-of-memory, viewflipper

I have images of cars and I am working on a 360 degree view on the car. I am using view flipper to load all the car images and get a 360 degree view. I have around 18 to 25 images. But it runs out of memory. What can I use to acheive this?

Answer (score 0):

load your images from a url using asyncTask.

[check this out.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5776851/load-image-from-url)

hope this will help.