# How to get byte Image From url in Android

Tags: java, android, json, android-studio

I am new to android.The Image is store in server by **Base64** format. so how can i get it from **server** to **My Project** and set to my ImageView using Json Object.
 Please Help me

Any help will be Appappreciated

Comment: Do you tried any thing, there is a lot of examples to perform this

Comment: Try with this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5776851/load-image-from-url

Comment: I have try lot of thing but not work

Comment: No one have idea what to do ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found easy solution:

```
byte[] img = Base64.decode(userHeader.GetImage(), Base64.DEFAULT);
                Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(img, 0, img.length);
                imageww.setImageBitmap(getCircleBitmap(bitmap));
```

Answer (score 5):

Try this:

Convert Url to byte[] first:

```
byte[] bitmapdata = getByteArrayImage(url);
```

Method:

```
private byte[] getByteArrayImage(String url){
         try {
                 URL imageUrl = new URL(url);
                 URLConnection ucon = imageUrl.openConnection();

                 InputStream is = ucon.getInputStream();
                 BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(is);

                 ByteArrayBuffer baf = new ByteArrayBuffer(500);
                 int current = 0;
                 while ((current = bis.read()) != -1) {
                         baf.append((byte) current);
                 }

                 return baf.toByteArray();
         } catch (Exception e) {
                 Log.d("ImageManager", "Error: " + e.toString());
         }
         return null;
    }
```

Now convert the byte[] to bitmap

```
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(bitmapdata , 0, bitmapdata .length);
```

And set your bitmap to your ImageView:

```
img= (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgView);
img.setImageBitmap(bitmap );
```

Comment: he want to set image from URL, how your code work for that

Answer (score 0):

Using Apache's commons-io-2.5 lib we can get using this function IOUtils.toByteArray(is)

```
public static String getByteArrayFromURL(final  String url) {
        String base64Image = "";
        ExecutorService executor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
        Future<String> result = executor.submit(new Callable<String>() {
            public String call() throws Exception {
                try {

                    URL imageUrl = new URL(url);
                    URLConnection ucon = imageUrl.openConnection();
                    InputStream is = ucon.getInputStream();
                    return Base64.encodeToString(IOUtils.toByteArray(is), Base64.NO_WRAP);
                } catch (Exception e) {

                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                return null;
            }
        });

        try {
            base64Image = result.get();
        } catch (Exception exception) {
            exception.printStackTrace();
        }
        return base64Image;
    }
```