# Android - How can i save the photos that are downloaded from firebase storage to the phone?

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-storage

I need to save the photos that i have downloaded from firebase storage to the phone for not downloading them again and again every time the program runs.

```
url = "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/****-*************.jpg"
Picasso.get().load(url).into(imageView);
```

I have no trouble viewing the picture but when I run the program again, I don't want the image to be reloaded.  How can I achieve this?

Comment: Picasso doesn't download your  image again and again, it just download once(on the first call of the url). The loading in the 2nd, 3rd, ... try is just Picasso browsing your image in its cache. Check your profiler for the data consumption and try it on network close.

Answer (score 1):

Better use Glide 4 instead of Picasso. Glide's image caching strategy is useful for these kind of purpose. 
More details : https://bumptech.github.io/glide/doc/caching.html

Answer (score 0):

first you will want convert the ImageView where you have the image to bitmap

```
BitmapDrawable drawable = (BitmapDrawable) imageView.getDrawable();
Bitmap bitmap = drawable.getBitmap();
```

now you can save the bitmap

```
try (FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(filename)) { //where filename is your path location file
    bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, out);     
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: I think there's got to be a better way. I don't want to wait for the image to come to imageView.

Comment: look this answer, I think that this can resolve your problem, after the convertion to bitmap you can save it how I describe in the answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/33012557/12355947

Comment: or save it directly like a byteArray.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to follow such steps to get good images and present to imageview.

1) Download from firebase and save to directory on android.
2) Display image from android directory.

Or you can download image using [link](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/android/download-files) from firebase.
It is not a good idea to get image from imageview.