# How to fetch image from url?

Tags: ios

I am using xcode version 8.
I want to create an app that shows images in a `UITableView`.  That image fetched from the url. And also want to know how to store and fetch from json.

Can anyone tell me

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Load image from url](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5776851/load-image-from-url)

Comment: Did you try doing it or search the web?

Answer (score 0):

If you're making a simple app then you can use NSURL for both these tasks, or you can take a look at either:

**AFNetworking:** https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking

This has a very simple extension on UIImageView for async download of photos as well as json support, or you can use

**Alamofire:** https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire

This is a networking library written purely in Swift if you're a swift enthusiast, with a lot of modern swift constructs and methods.

Answer (score -1):

```
func JSONParsing() {

    let url1 = URL(string: "yourURLHere")

    let request1 = URLRequest(url: url1!)

    let session1 = URLSession.shared

    let task1 = session1.dataTask(with: request1, completionHandler: {
        (data1 : Data?, response1 : URLResponse?, error1 : Error?) in

        if error1 != nil
        {
            print("\n Data Could Not Be Fetch. \n")
        }
        else
        {
            let jsonp = try! JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data1!, options: JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions.mutableContainers) as! NSDictionary
            //iterate dictionary and array

}
```