# How to load image from url in gridview

Tags: android, gridview, singleton

I'm a beginner in android,i save url of image in singleton after i need to send this image to another actitivty in gridview.
please someone can help me.

Comment: use intent.putextra("KEY","URL");

Comment: create a model class and pass data using parcelable

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Load image from url](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5776851/load-image-from-url)

Answer (score 0):

- The first at all, you need to know how to send data between activities.
  Refer to: [Intent Android](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html)
- The next, after you get the url on destinate activity, you need to display it.
  Refer to: [Display image from URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5776851/load-image-from-url)

An example for you: [Example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2091465/how-do-i-pass-data-between-activities-on-android)

Answer (score 0):

First send your image url to another `Activity` by your `Intent` from your current `activity`. Like -

```
Intent intent = new Intent(currentActivity, nextActivity);
input.putExtra("urlKey", "urlValue");
startActivity(intent);
```

And receive your image url from NextActivity. Like -

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
String imageUrl = intent.getStringExtra("urlKey");
```

And use third party library for loading image from web server/ url to view. Take a look on  [Picasso](http://square.github.io/picasso/). Use `Picasso` on your `Adapter` of `GridView`. Ex-

```
Picasso.with(context)
  .load(imageUrl)
  .resize(50, 50)
  .centerCrop()
  .into(yourImageView)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use 3rd party library like picasso then you can achieve your goal in few lines of code
Do the Following Steps:

1. add the following line in the dependency block of your build.gradle file

> dependencies  {  compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'  }

2. Then load the image into your image view:

Syntax:

> ```
> Picasso.with(this)
>    .load("YOUR IMAGE URL HERE")
>    .into(imageView);
> ```
>
> For example

```
Picasso.with(this)
                .load("https://www.samplecode.co/wp-content/uploads/2015/10/advertise.png")
                .into(imageView);
```

- For a gridview , you create an adapter and load the images with the position , refer this adapter class

  import android.app.Activity;
  import android.content.Context;
  import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
  import android.view.LayoutInflater;
  import android.view.View;
  import android.view.ViewGroup;
  import android.widget.ImageView;
  import android.widget.RatingBar;
  import android.widget.TextView;

  import com.drapp.BaseDrawerActivity;
  import com.drapp.R;
  import com.squareup.picasso.Picasso;

  import java.util.ArrayList;

  public class GridViewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter  {
      private Activity activity;

  ```
  Context context;
  ArrayList<String> image = new ArrayList<String>();
  ArrayList<String> name = new ArrayList<String>();
  private static LayoutInflater inflater = null;

  public GridViewAdapter(BaseDrawerActivity mainActivity, ArrayList<String> thumbnail, ArrayList<String> dish_name) {

      this.activity = mainActivity;
      this.context = mainActivity;
      image = thumbnail;
      name = dish_name;
  }

  public int getCount() {

      //return textnew1.length;

      int s = name.size();
      return s;
  }

  public Object getItem(int position) {
      return position;
  }

  @Override
  public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

      View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
              .inflate(R.layout.grid_item_layout, parent, false);
      // set the view's size, margins, paddings and layout parameters

      ViewHolder vh = new ViewHolder(v);
      return vh;


  }

  @Override
  public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {

      holder.productnametv.setText(name.get(position));


      if (image.get(position).equals("")) {
          holder.productimg.setImageResource(R.drawable.heart);
          holder.productimg.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
      } else {
          Picasso.with(context).load(image.get(position)).into(holder.productimg);
      }

  }

  public long getItemId(int position) {
      return position;
  }

  @Override
  public int getItemCount() {
      return name.size();
  }

  public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
      public TextView  productnametv;
      public ImageView productimg;
      public RatingBar rating;

      public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
          super(itemView);
          productnametv = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.grid_item_label);
          productimg = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.grid_item_image);
      }


  }
  ```

  }

Comment: i use your method but images not showing in gridview

Answer (score 0):

**try this if you dont want to use third party library**

```
 new DownloadImage(imamgeview).execute(userProfileUrl);
```

**create a Async Task**

```
 public class DownloadImage extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap> {
    CircleImageView bmImage;

    public DownloadImage(ImageView bmImage) {
        this.bmImage = (CircleImageView) bmImage;
    }

    protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... urls) {
        String urldisplay = urls[0];
        Bitmap mIcon11 = null;
        try {
            InputStream in = new java.net.URL(urldisplay).openStream();
            mIcon11 = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.d("Error", e.getStackTrace().toString());

        }
        return mIcon11;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result) {
        bmImage.setImageBitmap(result);
    }
}
```

**i hope you it will work in your case**