# how can I display range of images by URL instead drawable

Tags: android, imageurl

I'm trying to create a wallpaper application to display a range of images based on a drawable folder. How can I get this images from URL, i.e., to say get image by url instead?

```
public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private Context mContext;

    public Integer[] mThumbIds = {
        R.drawable.wallpaper_1,
        R.drawable.wallpaper_2,
        R.drawable.wallpaper_3,
        R.drawable.wallpaper_4,
        R.drawable.wallpaper_5,
        R.drawable.wallpaper_6,
        R.drawable.wallpaper_7,
        R.drawable.wallpaper_8,
        R.drawable.wallpaper_9,
        R.drawable.wallpaper_10
    };

    public ImageAdapter(Context c) {
        mContext = c;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mThumbIds.length;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return mThumbIds[position];
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ImageView imageView = new ImageView(mContext);
        imageView.setImageResource(mThumbIds[position]);
        imageView.setScaleType(imageView.getScaleType().CENTER_CROP);
        imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 400));
        return imageView;
    }

}
```

Comment: are you trying to load images form drawable folder or from remote server ?

Answer (score 0):

Lets say your image urls are something like `http://myweb.com/images/1.jpg` and it's counting like `2.jpg`, `3.jpg` and ...

Now you just must use this line in your `getView` method:

```
Picasso.with(getContext()).load("http://myweb.com/images/"+(position+1)+".jpg").fit().into(imageView);
```

BTW, you can add picasso library in your gradle:
`compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'`

**UPDATE:** if you have your urls in a list, you must change the `Picasso` line like this:

```
Picasso.with(getContext()).load(listOfUrls.get(position)).fit().into(imageView);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public String[] mThumbIds = {url1,url2,....,url10};
```

*In getView method add this code*

> ```
> URL url = new URL(mThumbIds [position]);
> Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(url.openConnection().getInputStream());
> imageView.setImageBitmap(bmp);
> ```

**Edited:**

[Load image from url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5776851/load-image-from-url)
In the link see the answer given **Kyle Clegg** 
how to load image from url to imageview in a separate thread.

Comment: `URL url = new URL(mThumbIds [position]);`
give me a `unhandled exception java.net.malformedurlexception`

AND  
`Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(url.openConnection().getInputStream());`

give me also : `unhandled exception java.io.ioexception`