# Get image from url and place it in imageview - Android

Tags: java, android

My url: http://www.deepanelango.me/wp%2Dcontent/uploads/2017/06/noyyal1.jpg

How to get image from the above mentioned url and set it in a imageview in android?
I have tried glide and here is my error log:

> I/Glide: Root cause (1 of 1)
>            java.net.SocketTimeoutException: connect timed out
>                at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
>                at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:334)
>                at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:196)
>                at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:178)
>                at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:356)
>                at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:605)
>                at com.android.okhttp.internal.Platform.connectSocket(Platform.java:113)
>                at com.android.okhttp.Connection.connectSocket(Connection.java:196)
>                at com.android.okhttp.Connection.connect(Connection.java:172)
>                at com.android.okhttp.Connection.connectAndSetOwner(Connection.java:367)
>                at com.android.okhttp.OkHttpClient$1.connectAndSetOwner(OkHttpClient.java:130)
>                at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:330)
>                at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:247)
>                at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.execute(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:457)
>                at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:126)
>                at com.bumptech.glide.load.data.HttpUrlFetcher.loadDataWithRedirects(HttpUrlFetcher.java:102)
>                at com.bumptech.glide.load.data.HttpUrlFetcher.loadData(HttpUrlFetcher.java:54)
>                at com.bumptech.glide.load.model.MultiModelLoader$MultiFetcher.loadData(MultiModelLoader.java:96)
>                at com.bumptech.glide.load.model.MultiModelLoader$MultiFetcher.startNextOrFail(MultiModelLoader.java:147)
>                at com.bumptech.glide.load.model.MultiModelLoader$MultiFetcher.onLoadFailed(MultiModelLoader.java:141)
>                at com.bumptech.glide.load.data.HttpUrlFetcher.loadData(HttpUrlFetcher.java:60)
>                at com.bumptech.glide.load.model.MultiModelLoader$MultiFetcher.loadData(MultiModelLoader.java:96)
>                at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.SourceGenerator.startNext(SourceGenerator.java:61)
>                at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.DecodeJob.runGenerators(DecodeJob.java:298)
>                at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.DecodeJob.runWrapped(DecodeJob.java:268)
>                at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.DecodeJob.run(DecodeJob.java:229)
>                at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1133)
>                at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607)
>                at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:761)
>                at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.executor.GlideExecutor$DefaultThreadFactory$1.run(GlideExecutor.java:413)

Comment: you can use Glide or Fresco Lib for this.

Comment: @DileepPatel I get error response from glide when I pass the url
My code: Glide.with(ctx).load(imageUrl).apply(RequestOptions().centerCrop()).into(iv)

Comment: @Deepan what error share with question

Comment: Glide.with(yourContext).load(Your Url).into(imageview);

Comment: please share your log error code

Comment: This question is asked many times before, please search before asking a question.

Comment: @RatilalChopda I have tried those solutions too. I get socket timeout exception but my internet is working fine and permissions for internet are also added.

Comment: @Deepan may be your image size is to high just check it

Comment: @FatihOzcan - I know that but my url is not working when I use those methods. That is why i specifically mentioned the url! Check my url before answering such obvious replies!

Comment: share your error log

Comment: @DileepPatel Here's my log!
W/Glide: Load failed for http://www.deepanelango.me/wp%2Dcontent/uploads/2017/06/noyyal1.jpg with size [394x394]
         class com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.GlideException: Failed to load resource
           Cause (1 of 1): class com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.GlideException: Fetching data failed, class java.io.InputStream, REMOTE
             Cause (1 of 1): class com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.GlideException: Fetch failed
               Cause (1 of 1): class java.net.SocketTimeoutException: connect timed out

Comment: @VishalYadav Thanks but didnt work

Comment: @DileepPatel may your image size is to high tried load it into webveiw

Comment: @RatilalChopda I will try it!

Comment: @Deepan let me know if it works or not

Comment: check my answer at this link, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5776851/load-image-from-url/47195793#47195793

Answer (score 0):

Use Picasso library

```
Picasso.with(context)
                .load(ImageURL)
                .into(imageView);
```

Comment: Have tried picasso too! Same as Glide. Check error log ;)

Answer (score 0):

Add Dependency

```
compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.8.0'
```

and

```
Glide.with(yourContext).load(Your Url).into(imageview);
```

Comment: Didnt work. Check error log.

Answer (score 0):

If it is only static images, then download it and add it to your app resources. 
If you have multiple non-static images, then you are best off using the [Glide](https://github.com/bumptech/glide) library, as it will take care of downloading, caching and much more.

Comment: I have tried Picasso, Glide, normal image caching - nothing worked with this url