# How to display image in a listview from json response in android

Tags: android, retrofit, imageurl

Hi in the below code am displaying data from json response using retrofit library.
using recylerview am displaying title,id,albumid as well as image.all are displaying except image .

But how to display image from url. can any one please help me
this is my adapter class.

.java

```
public class RecyclerViewAdapterForAlbum extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerViewAdapterForAlbum.ViewHolder> {

    private List<UserAlbum> item;
    Context context ;

    public RecyclerViewAdapterForAlbum(Context context, List<UserAlbum> item ) {
        Log.d("123", "RecyclerViewAdapter");
        this.item = item;
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        Log.d("123", "onCreateViewHolder");
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.activity_second, null);

        return new ViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        Log.d("123", "onBindViewHolder");
        holder.user_id.setText(String.valueOf(item.get(position).getId()));
        holder.album_id.setText(String.valueOf(item.get(position).getAlbumId()));
        holder.title.setText(item.get(position).getTitle());
        //Bitmap getBitMapFromUrl=null;
       holder.imageForText.setImageResource(item.get(position).getThumbnailUrl());
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        Log.d("123", "getItemCount");
        return item.size();
    }

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        public TextView album_id, user_id,title;
        public ImageView imageForText;

        public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            Log.d("123", "ViewHolder");


            user_id = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.user_id);
            album_id=(TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.album_id);
            title=(TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.title);
            imageForText=(ImageView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.img_id);


            itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
//                    int pos = getAdapterPosition();
//                    int userID=item.get(pos).getId();
//                    Intent myIntent = new Intent(v.getContext(), SecondActivity.class);
//                    myIntent.putExtra("userId",userID);
//                    context.startActivity(myIntent);

                }
            });
        }


    }
}
```

Comment: You only have the url of the image in the son. You need to fetch the actual image first. I'd recommend using a library like [Picasso](http://square.github.io/picasso/)

Comment: You can use [picasso](http://square.github.io/picasso/) , or [Glide](https://github.com/bumptech/glide)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Load image from url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5776851/load-image-from-url)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Using Picasso:**

Add this line to your app-level `build.gradle` file.

```
implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.71828'
```

And you can simply set image to `ImageView` by:

```
Picasso.get().load(item.get(position).getThumbnailUrl()).into(holder.imageForText);
```

**Using Glide:**

Add these lines to your app-level `build.gradle` file.

```
implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.8.0'
annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.8.0'
```

And you can simply set image to `ImageView` by:

```
GlideApp.with(this).load(item.get(position).getThumbnailUrl()).into(holder.imageForText);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use library for that, like Picasso

```
implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.71828'
```

To use it :

```
Picasso.get().load("IMG URL").into(YOURIMAGEVIEW);
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to use such type of libaray like picasso or universal image loader etc  for load image on Your ImageView like in this I am using picaso

implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.71828'

Picasso.get().load(item.get(position).getThumbnailUrl()).into(imageForText);