# Picasso Update to implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.71828' got error Picasso.with couldn't be resolved

Tags: android, version, picasso

I recently update to `com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.71828` from `com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2`.But while trying to run or build project got an error as `Picasso.with` couldn't be resolved.

Try to build or run project after

1.Clean project

2.invalid cache and restart

But still got the same. But if its revert back to `com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2` to make everything work fine. Is this known bug or any solution for this bug for `com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.71828` version?

Comment: that's because they have changed their library. Check theyr quick start or a migration guide to see what you need to do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They have changed the API. Take a look

https://github.com/square/picasso/commit/e7e919232fe2b15772a7fcd9e15ead2304c66fae

Here is the example:

```
Picasso.get().load("http://i.imgur.com/DvpvklR.png").into(imageView);
```

Answer (score 1):

From [this answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53299248/2289835)

Picasso syntax has been changed in latest update. and we need to use like:

```
Picasso.get().load("your_url").into(your_imageview);
```

For latest Picasso update, you can always [visit here.](http://square.github.io/picasso/)

Answer (score 1):

use `Picasso.get().load("ImageUrlHere").into(imageView);`

for more see here [Picasso](http://square.github.io/picasso/)