# NullPointerException with android AsyncTask and RecyclerView

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, nullpointerexception, android-asynctask

I have an AsyncTask class to download image from web and set it into in `ImageView` (referred from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5776851/load-image-from-url))

Relevant Activity code:

```java
    public class ListAdoptions extends AppCompatActivity {
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_list_adoptions);

            recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);

            mAdapter = new PetsAdapter(petList);
            RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext());
            recyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
            recyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
            recyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);

            preparePetData();
        }


        private void preparePetData() {

            DownloadImageTask imgtask = new DownloadImageTask((ImageView) findViewById(R.id.picture));
            imgtask.execute("https://i.ytimg.com/vi/opKg3fyqWt4/hqdefault.jpg");

            mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

        private class DownloadImageTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap> {
            ImageView bmImage;

            public DownloadImageTask(ImageView bmImage) {
                this.bmImage = bmImage;
            }

            protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... urls) {
                String urldisplay = urls[0];
                Bitmap mIcon11 = null;
                try {
                    InputStream in = new java.net.URL(urldisplay).openStream();
                    mIcon11 = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                return mIcon11;
            }

            protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result) {
                bmImage.setImageBitmap(result);
            }
        }
    }
```

Error:

```
Process: com.example.test3, PID: 8427
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.ImageView.setImageBitmap(android.graphics.Bitmap)' on a null object reference
        at com.example.petadoption.ListAdoptions$DownloadImageTask.onPostExecute(ListAdoptions.java:171)
        at com.example.petadoption.ListAdoptions$DownloadImageTask.onPostExecute(ListAdoptions.java:150)
        at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:695)
        at android.os.AsyncTask.-wrap1(Unknown Source:0)
        at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:712)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6541)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767)
```

Comment: Yeah, I am quite new to JAVA and android (One day old) so please dont judge x(

Comment: Strongly recommend you use a standard image loading library, such as [Glide](https://github.com/bumptech/glide/blob/master/README.md) or [Coil](https://github.com/coil-kt/coil/blob/master/README.md)

Comment: @AjahnCharles I got same error with glide "argument must not be null"

Comment: I meant replace the AsyncTask entirely. You should call Glide from the RV Adapter/ViewHolder.

Comment: I did that and got the same error

Comment: Then you're not getting your ImageView correctly... (but that should be far easier to fix without the AsyncTask)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your `bmImage` is always null. Most likely `findViewById(R.id.picture)` always null. Make sure that you defined ImageView with id "picture" and didn't miss at with plus in your XML layout file.
`android:id="@+id/picture"`

Answer (score 1):

Can''t see the whole code but message is null object... 
Make sure you defined bmImage in ListAdoptions like findViewById(R.id.bmImage) and check if this object exist in xml with id bmImage

Comment: bmimage is local variable to asynctask

Answer (score 1):

Things to do when dealing with null:

- make sure you spelled the name right
- add if statements to see when things are becoming null
- use the debugger and step through your code to see why the object is null

For some reason bmImage doesn't exist and i would recommend looking in your layouts and this class itself to find the null

Comment: bmImage is a local variable to asynctask