# My Json contains Image I want to show it in Image view

Tags: android, json, android-volley

Here is my json i want to show articleImage on an ImageView in Android.

```
 {"comboDTOArray": [
            {
                "articleActive": "1",
                "articleCode": "0CCE0000230",
                "articleImage": "double scoop combo cup.jpg",
                "articleName": "Double Cup/Cone",
                "articlePrice": "93.22",
                "articleType": "Combo",}]}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Load image from url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5776851/load-image-from-url)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need the complete image url in "articleImage" field and an image library for loading it into ImageView