# Async Task for downloading image into bitmap

Tags: android, multithreading, android-asynctask

I have RecyclerView, and in OnClick method I need get Bitmap image of element I clicked:

```
class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
            ImageView imgSticker;

            ViewHolder(View itemView) {
                super(itemView);
                imgSticker = itemView.findViewById(R.id.imgSticker);

                itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        if (mStickerListener != null) {
                            try {
                                URL url = new URL(stickerList.get(getLayoutPosition()));
                                image = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(url.openConnection().getInputStream());
                            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            } catch (IOException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }

                            mStickerListener.onStickerClick(image);
                        }
                        dismiss();
                    }
                });
            }
        }
```

But this doenst work, because I get exception, that it should be done in another tread, I know I need create class extends AsyncTask and override method "doInBackground", but it is difficult for me to understand what parametres I need write here:
 `class downloadStickersTask extends AsyncTask<?, ?, ?>` and how I should override doInBackgroundMethod. I am beginner at android, and threads are difficult for me

Comment: I have already found decision: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5776851/load-image-from-url

Answer (score 0):

```
if (mStickerListener != null) {
        new Thread(() -> {
            
                            try {
                                URL url = new URL(stickerList.get(getLayoutPosition()));
                                image = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(url.openConnection().getInputStream());
                            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            } catch (IOException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }

                            
                        }
            runOnUiThread(()->{
                mStickerListener.onStickerClick(image);
            });
        }).start();
dismiss();
```

try this

Comment: Thanks, but it doesnt work, when I call this method in other class I get 
` 

Can't create handler inside thread Thread[Thread-8,5,main] that has not called Looper.prepare()


`

Comment: are you using java 8 ?

Comment: I saw it in android studio folder:
"This notice is provided with respect to ASM Bytecode Manipulation 
Framework v5.0.3, which may be included with JRE 8, and JDK 8, and 
OpenJDK 8."