# display an image from an url, the activity stops

Tags: java, android

little problem, I would like to display an image from an url, without using (glide, picasso etc ...), I want to learn from the errors I make, here is my code, the activity stops , do you see something that I missed?

onCreate :

```
  String imgUrl = "https://st3.depositphotos.com/1008939/12603/i/950/depositphotos_126032722-stock-photo-roaring-singing-woman.jpg";
    ImageView img = findViewById(R.id.imageArtist);

    try {
        InputStream input = new java.net.URL(imgUrl).openStream();
        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input);
        img.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

xml :

```
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="@dimen/dim_170"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/dim_170"
    android:id="@+id/imageArtist"
    android:layout_below="@+id/txtViewTitleArtist"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/dim_15"
    tools:ignore="ContentDescription" />
```

thx for your help

Comment: Can you show the full error log when you crash?

Comment: NetworkOnMainThreadException. Clearly mentioned in Logcat. And too much tattoos ;-)

Comment: E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.card, PID: 24359
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.card/com.example.card.Activity.ArtistActivity}: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException

Comment: thx u blackapps, i'm new  in android, i learn,

Comment: See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5776903/11718077) it'll clear your doubts

Comment: Also a rule you should know about Android is to avoid big sized images. Images are showing in memory so, Android can kill your activity process if it is using to much memory.

Comment: You should use "Picasso" or "Glide" for loading the image from an URL. Check them out!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you are trying network operation in Application's main thread (in onCreate) . Before do that you should permit StrictMode ThreadPolicy.

```
StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder()
            .permitAll().build();
    StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);

    String imgUrl = "https://st3.depositphotos.com/1008939/12603/i/950/depositphotos_126032722-stock-photo-roaring-singing-woman.jpg";
    ImageView img = findViewById(R.id.imageArtist);

    try {
        InputStream input = new java.net.URL(imgUrl).openStream();
        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input);
        img.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Plesae check [this](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/StrictMode)

Comment: `Before do that you should permit StrictMode ThreadPolicy.` No No. Dont learn OP these dirty tricks. OP should use a thread to execute internet code. And you too!

Comment: He wants to learn from problem he mentioned . And it's for debugging or learning purpose only.