# how to set image from url for imageView

Tags: android, url, imageview

I wanna set Image in ImageView using Url for example I have this url

> http://www.google.iq/imgres?hl=en&biw=1366&bih=667&tbm=isch&tbnid=HjzjsaANDXVR9M:&imgrefurl=http://www.vectortemplates.com/raster-batman.php&docid=FxbVmggVf--0dM&imgurl=http://www.vectortemplates.com/raster/batman-logo-big.gif&w=2072&h=1225&ei=Zeo_UoSWIMaR0AXl_YHIBg&zoom=1

but there is no option to set url

Comment: you can use ImageLoader class or you can refer some link that how to fetch image from url???

Comment: Lack of efforts for solving the issue.

Comment: Take a look at [This Solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9288544/6444297).

Answer (score 69):

**EDIT:**

Create a class that extends [AsyncTask](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html)

```
public class ImageLoadTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Bitmap> {

    private String url;
    private ImageView imageView;

    public ImageLoadTask(String url, ImageView imageView) {
        this.url = url;
        this.imageView = imageView;
    }

    @Override
    protected Bitmap doInBackground(Void... params) {
        try {
            URL urlConnection = new URL(url);
            HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) urlConnection
                    .openConnection();
            connection.setDoInput(true);
            connection.connect();
            InputStream input = connection.getInputStream();
            Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input);
            return myBitmap;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        imageView.setImageBitmap(result);
    }

}
```

And call this like `new ImageLoadTask(url, imageView).execute();`

**Direct method:**

Use this method and pass your url as string. It returns a bitmap. Set the bitmap to your ImageView.

```
public static Bitmap getBitmapFromURL(String src) {
    try {
        Log.e("src",src);
        URL url = new URL(src);
        HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        connection.setDoInput(true);
        connection.connect();
        InputStream input = connection.getInputStream();
        Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input);
        Log.e("Bitmap","returned");
        return myBitmap;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Log.e("Exception",e.getMessage());
        return null;
    }
}
```

And then this to ImageView like so:

```
imageView.setImageBitmap(getBitmapFromURL(url));
```

And dont forget about this permission in maifest.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

**NOTE:**

Try to call this method from another thread or AsyncTask because we are performing networking operations.

Comment: In 1st method, instead of setting imageView directly from onPostExecute, use imageView.post(new Runnable() { public void run() { imageView.setImageBitmap(result); } });

Comment: @Tushar its not needed..onpostExecute() will call in UI thread.

Comment: Eres un crack, te mereces todo Jajajaj

Comment: For **Direct Method** you need to add this Code in `onCreate` method, Code Mentioned bellow 
        `StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = 
        new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
        StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);`

Answer (score 50):

You can also let Square's [Picasso](http://square.github.io/picasso/) library do the heavy lifting:

```
Picasso
    .get()
    .load("http://...")
    .into(imageView);
```

As a bonus, you get caching, transformations, and more.

Comment: But it work for .png type image url, it didn't worked for .svg url or for any other url to me . If there is any work around kindly share !!!

Answer (score 10):

Try:

```
URL newurl = new URL(photo_url_str); 
mIcon_val = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(newurl.openConnection() .getInputStream()); 
profile_photo.setImageBitmap(mIcon_val);
```

More from

1) [how-to-load-an-imageview-by-url-in-android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2471935/how-to-load-an-imageview-by-url-in-android).

2) [android-make-an-image-at-a-url-equal-to-imageviews-image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3118691/android-make-an-image-at-a-url-equal-to-imageviews-image)

Comment: Works like Gem!

Answer (score 8):

Using [Glide](https://github.com/bumptech/glide) library:

```
Glide.with(context)
  .load(new File(url)
  .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.ALL)
  .into(imageView);
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use either `Picasso` or `Glide`.

```
Picasso.get()
   .load(your_url)
   .into(imageView);


Glide.with(context)
   .load(your_url)
   .into(imageView);
```

Answer (score 1):

easy way to use [Aquery](https://code.google.com/p/android-query/) library  it helps to get direct load image from url

```
AQuery aq=new AQuery(this); // intsialze aquery
 aq.id(R.id.ImageView).image("http://www.vikispot.com/z/images/vikispot/android-w.png");
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the library SimpleDraweeView

```
<com.facebook.drawee.view.SimpleDraweeView
        android:id="@+id/badge_image"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
```

and now you can simply do:

```
 final Uri uri = Uri.parse(post.getImageUrl());
```

Answer (score 1):

For one-liner programmers,

```java
imageView.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new URL("https://www.vectortemplates.com/raster/batman-logo-big.gif").openConnection().getInputStream()));
```

Comment: Does this block the main/UI thread? Java noob here

Comment: Yep, it will. Make sense if the image size is large.

Answer (score 0):

if you are making a RecyclerView and using an adapter, what worked for me was:

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ADAPTERVIEWHOLDER holder, int position) {
    MODEL model = LIST.get(position);
    holder.TEXTVIEW.setText(service.getTitle());
    holder.TEXTVIEW.setText(service.getDesc());

    Context context = holder.IMAGEVIEW.getContext();
    Picasso.with(context).load(model.getImage()).into(holder.IMAGEVIEW);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

With the latest version of Picasso (2.71828 at the time of writing this answer), the `with` method has been deprecated.

So the correct way would be-

```
Picasso.get().load("https://<image-url>").into(imageView);
```

where `imageView` is the [ImageView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView) you want to load your image into.

Answer (score -2):

Try this :

```
ImageView imageview = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.your_imageview_id);
Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(new java.net.URL(your_url).openStream());  
imageview.setImageBitmap(bmp);
```

You can also try this : [Android-Universal-Image-Loader](https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader) for efficiently loading your image from `URL`