# How to set an array list to image view present inside a listview

Tags: java, android, imageview

I have a listview which contains ImageView i. Now I have an array list which contains URLS inside it like www.abc.jpg, www.def.jpg and so on. Now I want to insert these URLs as the source for the image view. Is it possible.?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ImageView` doesn't have any API that allows setting of urls that will be downloaded later on. You need to separately from the `ImageView` setup an asynchronous task that will download this image from the url, convert it to a `Bitmap` and then set it on `ImageView` with `setImageBitmap(Bitmap)`.

Comment: How to set up the Asynchronous task.?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18953632/how-to-set-image-from-url-for-imageview check this link

Comment: There are many libraries for Android out there that can help you with that like RoboSpice, Retrofit, Volley and others. If you wish to download it manually then http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html is a maybe not perfect but good enough solution.

Comment: Please see the updated question. I tried and I am getting network on main thread exception.

Answer (score 0):

As noted, you're doing network I/O in the main thread.  The stack trace identifies it as happening in onPostExecute.  In there, I see this code:

```
BitmapFactory.decodeStream(newurl.openConnection() .getInputStream()
```

That certainly looks like network I/O to me.

What I'm wondering is, you've got this lovely worker thread already, but you're doing a lot of work in onPostExecute() (main thread).  To prevent janky UI, I suggest you move as much of that computation into doInBackgroud() as possible.