# Why image not loading?

Tags: android, android-asynctask, imageview

I am working a demo for my project.

The XML file is as follow:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="${relativePackage}.${activityClass}" >

    <ImageView 

        android:id="@+id/imageview"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:visibility="visible"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:contentDescription="@string/content_description"
        />
</LinearLayout>
```

And my `Activity` is following to load the image into `ImageView`.
Implemented `AsyncTask` as inner class.

```
    public class LoadImageActivity extends Activity {

    ImageView image ;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.load_image);
        image = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageview);
        String url = "http://java.sogeti.nl/JavaBlog/wp-content/uploads/2009/04/android_icon_256.png";
        LoadImageAsync loadImageAsync = new LoadImageAsync(url, image);
        loadImageAsync.execute(url);    

    }
```

In `Activity`'s `onCreate` method I called the `AsyncTask` to load image

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.load_image);
    image = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageview);
    String url = "http://java.sogeti.nl/JavaBlog/wp-content/uploads/2009/04/android_icon_256.png";
    LoadImageAsync loadImageAsync = new LoadImageAsync(url, image);
    loadImageAsync.execute(url);    

}
```

In `AsyncTask` class I have the following code which is I followed [the Stack Overflow link related to this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18953632/how-to-set-image-from-url-for-imageview).

The AsyncTask class is below which I implemented as inner class to the Activity class.

```
public class LoadImageAsync extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap>{

    private String url;
    private ImageView imageView;

    public LoadImageAsync(String url, ImageView imageView) {
            this.url = url;
            this.imageView = imageView;
        }

    @Override
    protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... params) {         


        try {
            URL urlConnection = (URL) new URL(params[0]);
            HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) urlConnection
                    .openConnection();
            connection.setDoInput(true);
            connection.connect();
            InputStream input = connection.getInputStream();
            Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input);
            return myBitmap;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result) {

        imageView.setImageBitmap(result);
        super.onPostExecute(result);
    }

}
```

What wrong I did? or anything missed?

What are all need to consider when working on images?

And after this will move to loading images with `GridView`.

Comment: Change here from `loadImageAsync.execute(url);`  to `loadImageAsync.execute();`

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend to use Picasso 
Picasso.with(context).load("http://java.sogeti.nl/JavaBlog/wp-content/uploads/2009/04/android_icon_256.png").into(image);

So you don't need to worry about OutMemoryException that will most probably happen when you will implement this in the GridView

Answer (score 0):

The problem might be in your `ImageView` focus. Try to call `requestLayout` and/or `invalidate`:

```
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result) {
    imageView.requestLayout();
    imageView.setImageBitmap(result);
    imageView.invalidate(); //try this if it still not working
    super.onPostExecute(result);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [AQuery](http://code.google.com/p/android-query/) to load image from url :

AQuery aq = new AQuery(context);

```
aq.ajax(url, Bitmap.class, new AjaxCallback<Bitmap>() {
      @Override
      public void callback(String url, Bitmap object, AjaxStatus status) {
         imageView.setImageBitmap(object);
      }
});
```

**OR**

```
aq.id(imageView).image(url,true,true);
```

**Note :** please check more option which improve image loading,cache etc.