# Android - What's the fastest way to get drawable from url?

Tags: android, image, listview, android-imageview

In my news activity I need to load images from the web server to place them in `ListView`.
I have found many ways to load image from url. I find this solution as the most effective:
[how to set image from url for imageView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18953632/how-to-set-image-from-url-for-imageview)

It works fine when I have 1-4 news in a list.
But the problem occurs when I load the past 30 days news. My list becomes very long and the images aren't get loaded even after 2-3 minutes though I make all the thumbs 4-5 KB. Even if I scroll the list, images are getting unloaded again.

[In this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y6cRd.png) I test the app on Genymotion. I opened the activity and chose the news from past 30 days. Everything works fine because I use virtual server.

But when I test it on my phone, with real server, the problem occurs. Is there any optimal way?

Comment: use glide library (preferable) and hold image cache with it.

Comment: Thank You. Glide is very effective.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is many library that can do the job for you :

[Picasso](http://square.github.io/picasso/) which is the most famous

[Glide](https://github.com/bumptech/glide)

[Universal image loader](https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader)

That just some example.

Comment: For me, Glide is fastest

Comment: I have not tried it yet, I'm familiar with picaso and Universal image loader which are very good, but I trust you about glide.

Comment: Glide works perfectly. Very simple code and very easy loading. Thank You!