# I want to show a picture from URL in my recyclerview

Tags: android, android-studio, url, android-recyclerview, android-imageview

I have a recyclerview which I populate from an API , there is a URL of a picture I want to show in my imageview, I tried few methods it gives Network Thread exception,

My Adapter Class,

```
 @Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    ItemPayload model = list.get(position);
    Log.d("aaa",model.getTrack().getName().toString());

    String image = model.getTrack().getAlbum().getImages().get(position).getUrl();
    URL newurl = null;
    try {
        newurl = new URL(image);
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    Bitmap mIcon_val = null;
    try {
        HttpURLConnection conn= (HttpURLConnection)newurl.openConnection();
        conn.setDoInput(true);
        conn.connect();
        int length = conn.getContentLength();
        int[] bitmapData =new int[length];
        byte[] bitmapData2 =new byte[length];
        InputStream is = conn.getInputStream();
        BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();

        mIcon_val = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is,null,options);

        holder.songCover.setImageBitmap(mIcon_val);
        
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }



    holder.textSong.setText(model.getTrack().getName());
    holder.textArtist.setText(model.getTrack().getArtists().get(0).getName());
    holder.textTrack.setText(model.getTrack().getAlbum().getTotal_tracks().toString());
    String url = model.getTrack().getExternal_urls().getSpotify();
    holder.textSong.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent viewIntent =
                    new Intent("android.intent.action.VIEW", Uri.parse(url));
            viewIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            context.startActivity(viewIntent);
        }
    });

}
```

Does Anyone know a easier way to do it? or any fixes?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to set image from url for imageView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18953632/how-to-set-image-from-url-for-imageview)

Comment: @Sniffer thanks but it didn't work, I used picasso library then it worked!

Comment: There are lot's of open source libraries available to load image from url such as [Picasso](https://github.com/square/picasso), [Glide](https://github.com/bumptech/glide), etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Picasso library for the same.

Permission in android manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

Add Picasso in app level build.gradle

```
implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
```

Loading image

```
Picasso.get().load(model.getTrack().getAlbum().getImages().get(position).getUrl()).into(holder.songCover);
```

Answer (score 2):

Loading images using `HttpURLConnection` load on main thread and stops the processing of the app or causes ANR. It's recommended you load images in background thread.
[Glide library](https://github.com/bumptech/glide) is image loading library which does the tasks easily for you.

Use glide to load the images

```
  implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.12.0'
```

Sample Code

```
 Glide
    .with(myFragment)
    .load(url)
    .centerCrop()
    .placeholder(R.drawable.loading_spinner)
    .into(myImageView);
```