# Loading images from xml file into imageview

Tags: android, xml, xml-parsing

This question is asked many times in stackoverflow but still i didn't got answer, hence i posted this question.

Using parser concept of xml file am reading an xml file in android. In that xml file am declaring both images and texts. Am clear about displaying text from xml file but i tried of displaying image url from xml file into imageview. I referred stackoverflow but still i don't know how to display image from my xml file.

Here is my xml file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<test>
<Category Type="entertainment">
<channel_name>sunmusic</channel_name>
<image_url>http://xxxx/xxxx/Images/news1.png</image_url>
</Category>
<Category Type="sports">
<channel_name>neosports</channel_name>
<image_url>http://xxxx/xxxx/Images/news2.png</image_url>
</Category>
</test>
```

I loaded all my images in my server and the links are working fine. Please help me resolving this issue.

Customlistview.java

```
public class CustomListViewAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<TV> {
    Activity context;
    List<tv> tvlist;

    public CustomListViewAdapter(Activity context, List<TV> tvlist) {
        super(context, R.layout.list_item, tvlist);
        this.context = context;
        this.tvlist = tvlist;
    }

    /*private view holder class*/
    private class ViewHolder 
    {
        ImageView imageView;
        TextView txtCname;
            }

    public TV getItem(int position) 
    {
        return tvlist.get(position);
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) 
    {
        ViewHolder holder;
        LayoutInflater inflater = context.getLayoutInflater();

        if (convertView == null) 
        {
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, null);
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.txtCname = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.channel_name);
            holder.imageView = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.thumbnail);
            convertView.setTag(holder);
        } 
        else 
        {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        TV laptop = (TV) getItem(position); 
        holder.txtCname.setText(laptop.getChannelName());       
        holder.imageView.setImageBitmap(laptop.getImageBitmap());


        return convertView;
    }
}
```

tv.java

```
public class TV 
{   
        private String channel_name;               
        private String imageURL;
        private Bitmap imageBitmap;
        private String type;

        public String getChannelName() 
        {
            return channel_name;
        }
        public void setChannelName(String type) 
        {
            this.type = type;
        }   
        public String getType() 
        {
            return type;
        }
        public void setType(String channel_name) 
        {
            this.channel_name = channel_name;
        }   
        public String getImageURL() 
        {
            return imageURL;
        }
        public void setImageURL(String imageURL) 
        {
            this.imageURL = imageURL;
        }
        public Bitmap getImageBitmap() 
        {
            return imageBitmap;
        }
        public void setImageBitmap(Bitmap imageBitmap) 
        {
            this.imageBitmap = imageBitmap;
        }
    }
```

mainactivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener, OnItemClickListener 
{
    Button button;
    ListView listView;
    List<TV> tvlist;
    CustomListViewAdapter listViewAdapter;
    static final String URL = "http://xxxx/xxxx/Images/channeltest.xml";


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        findViewsById();
        button.setOnClickListener(this);
        listView.setOnItemClickListener(this);
    }

    private void findViewsById() 
    {
        button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
        listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.laptopList);
    }

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) 
    {

    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) 
    {
        GetXMLTask task = new GetXMLTask(this);
        task.execute(new String[] { URL });
    }


    private class GetXMLTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, List<TV>> 
    {
        private Activity context;
        public GetXMLTask(Activity context) 
        {
            this.context = context;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(List<TV> tvlist) 
        {
            listViewAdapter = new CustomListViewAdapter(context, tvlist);
            listView.setAdapter(listViewAdapter);
        }


        private String getXmlFromUrl(String urlString) 
        {
            StringBuffer output = new StringBuffer("");
            try 
            {
                InputStream stream = null;
                URL url = new URL(urlString);
                URLConnection connection = url.openConnection();
                HttpURLConnection httpConnection = (HttpURLConnection) connection;
                httpConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
                httpConnection.connect();

                if (httpConnection.getResponseCode() == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) 
                {
                    stream = httpConnection.getInputStream();
                    BufferedReader buffer = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(stream));
                    String s = "";
                    while ((s = buffer.readLine()) != null)
                        output.append(s);
                }

            } 
            catch (Exception ex) 
            {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
            return output.toString();

        }  

        @Override
        protected List<TV> doInBackground(String... urls) 
        {
            List<TV> tvlist = null;
            String xml = null;
            for (String url : urls) 
            {
                xml = getXmlFromUrl(url);
                InputStream stream = new ByteArrayInputStream(xml.getBytes());
                tvlist = MsenseParsar.parse(stream);

                for (TV tv : tvlist) 
                {
                    String imageURL = tv.getImageURL();
                    Bitmap bitmap = null;
                    BitmapFactory.Options bmOptions = new BitmapFactory.Options();
                    bmOptions.inSampleSize = 1;

                    try 
                    {
                        bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new URL(imageURL).openStream(), null, bmOptions);
                    } 
                    catch (MalformedURLException e) 
                    {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } 
                    catch (IOException e) 
                    {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    tv.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                }
            }
        return tvlist;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: did u try the code in my post??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you have is xml. You need to parse the tag's first. Get the url and then set the downloaded image to `ImageView`.

To parse use XmlPullParser. Exammple @

http://developer.android.com/training/basics/network-ops/xml.html

Once you parse

[How to load an ImageView by URL in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2471935/how-to-load-an-imageview-by-url-in-android)

Example:

```
 public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    ImageView i;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        i = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
        new TheTask().execute();

    }

class TheTask extends AsyncTask<Void,Bitmap,Bitmap>
{

    @Override
    protected Bitmap doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
         Bitmap bitmap = null;
        try {
            bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream((InputStream)new URL("http://a3.twimg.com/profile_images/670625317/aam-logo-v3-twitter.png").getContent());
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return bitmap;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        i.setImageBitmap(result);

    }

}

}
```

Edit:

```
 tv.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
```

Cannot update ui from a non ui thread. `doInbackground` is invoked on the background thread.

Edit2:

Modify the below accordingly

I am parsing xml from assests folder.

```
 InputStream is = MainActivity.this.getResources()
      .getAssets().open("newxml.xml");
```

XML to parse with dummy images

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<test>
<Category Type="entertainment">
<channel_name>sunmusic</channel_name>
<image_url>http://a3.twimg.com/profile_images/670625317/aam-logo-v3-twitter.png</image_url>
</Category>
<Category Type="sports">
<channel_name>neosports</channel_name>
<image_url>http://a3.twimg.com/profile_images/740897825/AndroidCast-350_normal.png</image_url>
</Category>
</test>
```

Make sure you get the xml from url using asynctask. Download UIL and add the jar to libs folder.

```
public class MainActivity extends ListActivity {

    ImageView i;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        //setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        try
        {
           InputStream is = MainActivity.this.getResources()
      .getAssets().open("newxml.xml");
        ParseXml pxml = new ParseXml();
        ArrayList<Entry> all=pxml.getList(is);
        LazyAdapter adapter = new LazyAdapter(this,all);
        setListAdapter(adapter);
        }catch(Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```

ParseXml

```
public class ParseXml {


    private static final String ns = null;
    InputStream is;
    ArrayList<Entry> all;
    public ArrayList<Entry> getList(InputStream is) {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        this.is= is;
        try
        {
        XmlPullParser parser = Xml.newPullParser();
        parser.setFeature(XmlPullParser.FEATURE_PROCESS_NAMESPACES, false);
        parser.setInput(is, null);
        parser.nextTag();
         all=readFeed(parser);
        }catch(Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return  all;
    }
    private ArrayList<Entry> readFeed(XmlPullParser parser) throws XmlPullParserException, IOException {
        ArrayList<Entry> entries = new ArrayList<Entry>();

        parser.require(XmlPullParser.START_TAG, ns, "test");
        while (parser.next() != XmlPullParser.END_TAG) {
            if (parser.getEventType() != XmlPullParser.START_TAG) {
                continue;
            }
            String name = parser.getName();
            // Starts by looking for the entry tag
            if (name.equals("Category")) {
                entries.add(readEntry(parser));
            } else {
                skip(parser);
            }
        }  
        return entries;
    }
    private Entry readEntry(XmlPullParser parser) throws XmlPullParserException, IOException {
        parser.require(XmlPullParser.START_TAG, ns, "Category");
        String summary = null;
        String link = null;
        while (parser.next() != XmlPullParser.END_TAG) {
            if (parser.getEventType() != XmlPullParser.START_TAG) {
                continue;
            }
            String name = parser.getName();
           if (name.equals("channel_name")) {
                summary = readChannel(parser);
            } else if (name.equals("image_url")) {
                link = readUrl(parser);
            } else {
                skip(parser);
            }
        }
        return new Entry(summary, link);
    }
    private String readChannel(XmlPullParser parser) throws IOException, XmlPullParserException {
        parser.require(XmlPullParser.START_TAG, ns, "channel_name");
        String title = readText(parser);
        parser.require(XmlPullParser.END_TAG, ns, "channel_name");
        Log.i("...........",title);
        return title;
    }
    private String readUrl(XmlPullParser parser) throws IOException, XmlPullParserException {
        parser.require(XmlPullParser.START_TAG, ns, "image_url");
        String title = readText(parser);
        parser.require(XmlPullParser.END_TAG, ns, "image_url");
        Log.i("...........",title);
        return title;
    }
    // For the tags title and summary, extracts their text values.
    private String readText(XmlPullParser parser) throws IOException, XmlPullParserException {
        String result = "";
        if (parser.next() == XmlPullParser.TEXT) {
            result = parser.getText();
            parser.nextTag();
        }
        return result;
    }
    private void skip(XmlPullParser parser) throws XmlPullParserException, IOException {
        if (parser.getEventType() != XmlPullParser.START_TAG) {
            throw new IllegalStateException();
        }
        int depth = 1;
        while (depth != 0) {
            switch (parser.next()) {
            case XmlPullParser.END_TAG:
                depth--;
                break;
            case XmlPullParser.START_TAG:
                depth++;
                break;
            }
        }
     }
}
```

LazyAdapter

```
public class LazyAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

private Activity activity;
private ArrayList<Entry> data;
private LayoutInflater inflater=null;
public ImageLoader imageLoader; 
DisplayImageOptions options;

public LazyAdapter(Activity a, ArrayList<Entry> d) {
    activity = a;
    data=d;
    inflater = (LayoutInflater)activity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    File cacheDir = StorageUtils.getOwnCacheDirectory(a, "MyFolderCache");


 // Get singletone instance of ImageLoader
   imageLoader = ImageLoader.getInstance();
 // Create configuration for ImageLoader (all options are optional)
    ImageLoaderConfiguration config = new ImageLoaderConfiguration.Builder(a)
              // You can pass your own memory cache implementation
             .discCacheExtraOptions(1024, 1024, CompressFormat.PNG, 100)
             .discCache(new UnlimitedDiscCache(cacheDir)) // You can pass your own disc cache implementation
             .discCacheFileNameGenerator(new HashCodeFileNameGenerator())
             .enableLogging()
             .build();
 // Initialize ImageLoader with created configuration. Do it once.
 imageLoader.init(config);
    //imageLoader.init(ImageLoaderConfiguration.createDefault(a));
   // imageLoader=new ImageLoader(activity.getApplicationContext());
    options = new DisplayImageOptions.Builder()
    .showStubImage(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
    .cacheInMemory()
    .cacheOnDisc()
    .displayer(new RoundedBitmapDisplayer(20))
    .build();
}



public int getCount() {
    return data.size();
}

public Object getItem(int position) {
    return position;
}

public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View vi=convertView;
    ViewHolder vh = new ViewHolder();;
    if(convertView==null)
    {

    vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row, null);   
    vh.iv=(ImageView)vi.findViewById(R.id.imageView1); 
    vh.pb= (ProgressBar)vi.findViewById(R.id.pb); 
    vh.tv = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    vh.tv1= (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.textView2);

    }
    Entry entry = data.get(position);
    vh.tv.setText(entry.channel);
    vh.tv1.setText(""+position);
    display(vh.iv,entry.url , vh.pb);
    //imageLoader.displayImage(data.get(position).toString(), image,options);

    return vi;
}

public void display(ImageView img, String url, final ProgressBar spinner)
{
    imageLoader.displayImage(url, img, options, new ImageLoadingListener() {
        @Override
        public void onLoadingStarted(String imageUri, View view) {
         spinner.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
        @Override
        public void onLoadingFailed(String imageUri, View view, FailReason failReason) {
         spinner.setVisibility(View.GONE);


        }
        @Override
        public void onLoadingComplete(String imageUri, View view, Bitmap loadedImage) {
         spinner.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
        @Override
        public void onLoadingCancelled(String imageUri, View view) {

        }

});
}
 public static class ViewHolder
 {
  ImageView iv;
  TextView tv,tv1;
  ProgressBar pb;

 }
}
```

row.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
 <ProgressBar 
    android:id="@+id/pb"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

 <TextView
     android:id="@+id/textView1"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_above="@+id/textView2"
     android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
     android:layout_marginBottom="21dp"
     android:layout_marginLeft="31dp"
     android:text="TextView" />

 <TextView
     android:id="@+id/textView2"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView1"
     android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
     android:text="TextView" />

  </RelativeLayout>
```

Snap

[image]

Comment: @Ragunandhan i tried [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3118691/android-make-an-image-at-a-url-equal-to-imageviews-image] [1] it is throwing malfomed exception error

Comment: @AndroidOptimist post what you tried and the error in your post

Comment: @AndroidOptimist check if the url is right usually error happens if no connection can be made

Comment: @AndroidOptimist updating ui from `doInbackground` is not possible. Show us 1 valid image url.

Comment: @Ragunandhan i cannot post my url here as cause that belongs to particular concern. I tested with that url, when i googled, i can see the image

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/43991/discussion-between-raghunandan-and-androidoptimist)

Comment: @Ragunandhan for testing i loaded [http://a3.twimg.com/profile_images/740897825/AndroidCast-350_normal.png] url too, but no result